# .net framework 4.6.1 is not enabling TLS1.2

Tags: c#, tls1.2, .net-4.6.1

I have created a dummy C# project in visual studio 2015 and the target .net framework is 4.6.1 , this application just tries to connect to website which is TLS1.2 enabled.

i am using C#  HttpWebRequest class to connect to it

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
```

The only thing is this particular line excutes in a separate dll however the project for this dll is also targeting 4.6.1 .

whenever application tries to connect to website, its throws an error 
**"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."**

However when i add this line then it works

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

My question is, As per documentation if my target framework is 4.6.1 i need not to add above line and it should work regardless

Please let me know what i am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ensured the machine you're hosting the site on has TLS 1.2 enabled?  Even if the calling application communicates over TLS 1.2, the machine it's communicating with may not have TLS 1.2 enabled which could result in failed handshakes.  Should also mention that older versions of Windows server OS's (2008 R2) require an extra registry setting than newer ones to enable TLS 1.2

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for your reply. i did not think about it as site was working fine on webbrowser like ie or chrome. However i  will double check it

Comment: Yeah, browsers typically try the most secure protocol and fallback on weaker ones unless specifically set up not to do that.  For reference, ensure that in your server's registry that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > SecurityProviders > SCHANNEL > Protocols has a key named `TLS 1.2`.  That key should have a key under it named `Server` with a value of `Enabled` set to DWORD hexadecimal 1.  If you're running on 2008 R2 (or earlier OS's that support TLS 1.2), you'll also need to include a value of `DisabledByDefault` set to DWORD hexadecimal 0

Comment: i tried setting TLS 1.2 enabled in registry on my windows 2012 r2, but no luck. the only thing now i can think of is appache server fronting my test website,  but i checked httpd-ssl.conf it has TLS1.2 enabled. not sure what else can stop this

Comment: @NitinChopra Was this ever resolved?